# Flatten list of dictionaries in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I'm getting data with Facebook Insights API and there are nested columns in the data I get. I tried separating them by index but failed.

column I want to split:

```py
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '1'}]
```

the state i want to translate:

```
actions_video_view  actions_link_click
 1                   1
```

```py
xx = dataframe['actions'].apply(pd.Series).merge(dataframe["index"],
        right_index=True,
        left_index=True).melt(id_vars=['index'],
            value_name='actions')
xx2 = xx['action_type'].apply(pd.Series).merge(xx["index"],
        right_index=True, 
        left_index=True)
xx2 = xx2.loc[xx2['action_type'] == 'video_view', ["value", "index"]]
```

when i run this code i get the following error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc      
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'action_type'
```

I want to separate the column according to the keys and add it as a dataframe column, which way can I use for this?

An example of how it looks in the data:

```
actions
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '1'}]
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '3'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '3'}]
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '5'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '5'}]
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '6'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '6'}]
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '7'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '7'}]
```

if i want to apply:

```
actions_link_click  actions_video_view
1                    1
3                    3
5                    5
6                    6
7                    7
```

Comment: I have an answer which can help you in converting that string into a dataframe, but whats the second part of you question?

Comment: please show a bit more data where you got this dictionary as string from or how it is saved

Comment: it is actually a big difference if your input dictionary is a list or a string. thanks for editing your question. the data which is a list, containing 2 dictionarys is in one single column (each list of dicts in every row) and your output ( `actions_link_click` and `actions_video_view`) should be TWO columns or also both in one column ?

Comment: both should be in separate columns

Answer (score 0):

This does the job,

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("action_type")
new_df = pd.DataFrame([])

for action in df["action_type"].unique():
  new_df[f"actions_{action}"] = list(grouped_df.get_group(action)["value"])
```

Output -

|  | actions_link_click | actions_video_view |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 | 7 |

Comment: "[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '1'}]"
an example of a row from the column in this data actually I want to apply the conversion here on a dataframe

Comment: Okay so each row has a list?

Comment: Yes, I tried the above method but I had a problem like this

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: @AhmetBuğraBUĞA Can you share the data? That way I could help you the best.

Comment: sorry, it is not possible to share because the data is hidden, the column structure in the dataframe comes as a dictionary in the list. I guess it doesn't allow me to use the method here because it is dtype:object

Comment: @AhmetBuğraBUĞA Can you give a sample of it in the question itself? Lemme know if you edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look on how that data is generated like that to each row of a dataframe. I think that is not straightforward. But for your current problem, here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def convert_df(col):
    tmp = col.apply(pd.Series)
    out = (tmp.assign(idx=tmp.groupby('action_type').cumcount())
    .pivot(index='idx', columns='action_type', values='value')
    .add_prefix('actions_').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index(drop=True))
    return out

rows = [[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '1'}],
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '3'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '3'}],
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '5'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '5'}],
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '6'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '6'}],
[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '7'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '7'}],]


df = pd.DataFrame({'actions' : rows})
df = pd.json_normalize(df['actions'])

df = pd.concat([
    convert_df(df[0]),
    convert_df(df[1])
], axis=1)
print(df)

  actions_link_click actions_video_view
0                  1                  1
1                  3                  3
2                  5                  5
3                  6                  6
4                  7                  7
```

Comment: I have a dataframe and the values in the column come in like this:

`[{'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '1'}]`

I want to extract the values inside this column

Comment: please edit this to the question. but still, the goal is not quite clear, you can't just extract this in the column because the desired goal you have shown are 2 columns. I gave you all the tools you need